# signature file vs bloom filter in c

Tags: c, bloom-filter

I found the concept of bloom filter very near to signature file, but I might be wrong.
Is it necessary to implement it as an array, or I can implement the bloom filter with the same concept by a file? 
I have written this code in c. but was it a good way? or implementing it by a file isn't a good idea?

Comment: What make you think that it's that the concepts are similar?

Comment: @MichaelWalz if I implement it with the file instead of array, isn't it called signature file? I'm sorry for not having enough information

Comment: You'd normally use a bloom filter to reduce how often you need to go to a more expensive but more reliable mechanism -- but not to fully replace one.  It may be worthwhile to do that when the filter is faster/smaller than the other mechanism -- introducing the extra overhead of file access into the filter may reduce the advantages of using it.

Comment: @Dmitri thanks, these were the differences between signature file and bloom filter? so signature file is the file implementation of the bloom filter?

Comment: I agree with @Dmitri but I can't figure out what a signature file actually is, can you provide some information about it?